# return the first node of a std::list created in a function

Tags: c++

Interview query: create a function that will return the first node from a linked list created inside the function; use std::list.

```
std::list<int> function()
{   
  std::list<int> l;
  l.push_back(1);
  l.push_back(2);
  l.push_back(3);
  return l.front();
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

EDIT: the question was to return the node and not the value of the first node.

Comment: it then should be `int function()`.

Comment: the question seems to pull in two directions.  Usually a node in a linked list would be more than just the value contained (it would also include a pointer to the next node).  But std::list hides its actual node types as an implementation detail, only giving you access to the value contained (in this case forcing you to return an int, as others have suggested)

Comment: maybe the point is to test your knowledge of local variables (created on the stack, destroyed when the function exits) versus allocated (created on the heap using 'new', persists after the function exits).  Returning an iterator to a local variable would be a bad idea because it would not exist for the iterator to be dereferenced

Comment: As far as I understood they were asking to return the node and not the  value of the node.  So creating a std::list<int*> l; int *xx = new int(1); ll.push_back(xx); would be ok?

Comment: No. Just because your list holds pointers instead of ints doesn't change the fundamental issue here. The fundamental issue is that the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: There are two possibilities: either the interviewer worded the question wrongly, or it's a trick question.

Answer (score 1):

The public interface of `std::list` is not defined in terms of nodes and values. It is defined for a container of *elements* of type `value_type`. Hence you can *not* access the "nodes" of the linked list, only its elements.

If you want to return the first element from a local `std::list` from a function then you must return a *copy* of the element, as all local objects will be destroyed when the function body goes out of scope.

```
int func() {
  std::list<int> l { 1, 2, 3 };

  return l.front(); // Return a copy of the first element.
} // l gets destroyed here.
```

The purpose of this interview query is probably to check that you understand the mechanics of local object lifetime.

For instance, you can *not* return a reference or pointer to a local automatic object from inside a function:

```
int& func() { // Notice return type.
  std::list<int> l { 1, 2, 3 };

  return l.front(); // Return a reference to the first element.
} // l gets destroyed here.

int main() {
    const int& number = func(); // Dangling reference!
    std::cout << number;        // The UB deamons come!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the value, change it to

```
int function()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the 'interview query' was a joke. Following Code works in the Visual Studio:

```
struct Node // an assumption !!
{
    Node* next_;
    Node* prev_;
    int data_;
};

Node function()
{   
  std::list<int> l;
  l.push_back(1);
  l.push_back(2);
  l.push_back(3);
  Node** p = reinterpret_cast< Node** >( &l.front() );
  return *reinterpret_cast< Node* >(p-2);
}
```

;-)